# I'm using jquery to drag, drop and append and draggable to a droppable, but when I do, the draggable disappears

Tags: jquery, append, draggable, droppable

This is my first post onstackoverflow. I searched my issue and saw a link sort of in the neighborhood of my issue, but nothing exactly.

Anyway, so here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigyellow/7w52f5rp/) link.

Here's the code:

```
    $(function() {
        $('#armie').append('<div id="test_slide"></div>');
        $("#test_slide").draggable({
        });

        var position_orig       = $("#test_slide").position();
        var position_orig_left  = position_orig.left;
        var position_orig_top   = position_orig.top;
        var position_curr       = null;
        var position_curr_left  = null;
        var position_curr_top   = null;

        $("#square1").droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                if (1 == 2) {
                    position_curr = $("#test_slide").position();
                    position_curr_left = position_curr.left;
                    position_curr_top = position_curr.top;
                    var needed_offset_left = position_orig_left - position_curr_left;
                    var needed_offset_top   = position_orig_top - position_curr_top;
                    $("#test_slide").animate({left: '+=' +needed_offset_left+ 'px', top: '+=' +needed_offset_top+ 'px'}, "slow");
                } else {
                    //$(this).append($("#test_slide"));
                    ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));
                    alert("square1 html" + $(this).html());
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

css:

```
    #armie {
        position:absolute;
        width:120px;
        height:120px;
        top:400px;
        left:400px;
        border:4px solid #000;
        z-index:50;
    }
    #test_slide {
        position:absolute;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background-color:#f00;
        top:10px;
        left:10px;
        z-index:100;
    }
    #square1 {
        display:inline;
        position:absolute;
        top:50px;
        left:20px;
        width:150px;
        height:150px;
        background-color:blue;
        z-index:5;
    }
    #square2 {
        display:inline;
        position:absolute;
        top:400px;
        left:700px;
        width:150px;
        height:150px;
        background-color:yellow;
    }
    #square3 {
        display:inline;
        position:absolute;
        top:50px;
        left:500px;
        width:150px;
        height:150px;
        background-color:purple;
    }
    #square4 {
        display:inline;
        position:absolute;
        top:500px;
        left:175px;
        width:150px;
        height:150px;
        background-color:black;
    }
    #square5 {
        display:inline;
        position:absolute;
        top:300px;
        left:80px;
        width:150px;
        height:150px;
        background-color:green;
    }
```

and markup:

```
<div id="armie">
</div>
<div id="square1">
</div>
<div id="square2">
</div>
<div id="square3">
</div>
<div id="square4">
</div>
<div id="square5">
</div>
```

It's easier to see things if you just go to the fiddle link. Anyway, so I want to be able to drag the red div into the blue one conditionally. Right now, I just have the if (1==2) silliness, but eventually the results of an ajax call will be the conditional to either have the red div snap back or get appended to the blue (square1) div.

The first part works fine. If I set the conditional to if (1)...no matter where I drag the red square to within the blue square, it goes right back and is nicely centered. But if I have if (1==2)..., while the red square gets appended to the blue one and square1 appears to have the contents of the red square (as proven by the alert statement) the red square disappears (as you can see for yourself with the fiddle). At this point I'm a little stumped. square1 is reporting that it has the red div, yet there's no visual evidence of this and if I attempt to drag it again, it's not even like it's there but just invisible. And it's not a zindex thing either, as I checked that value and it's still set. And to make sure of this, when I dropped the red div onto the blue one, I didn't put it directly over, so some of the red div should still show. It literally just disappears.

Any idea how I should go about solving this? I've tried a few different approaches and nothing has worked. I tried cloning the div, but I can't get any love. Thanks for taking the time to look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see what the issue was. I was correct in that square1 did indeed get the test_slide div. So what was the problem? It gets it with it's top and left properties set relative to when it picked it up from the armie div. So in other words, at the time it's appended, it's top and left are roughly in the -300 range for both. So then once it gets appended, -300 top (or so) from square1 and -300 (or so) left from square1 lands up with an element that's off the page. Simply adding

`ui.draggable.css({top:10, left:10, position:'absolute'});`

after the detach statement sets the position relative to square1, so that solves the issue! I'm a happy camper! Maybe this will help someone else not go through a day of trying to figure this out.